# Using button to call method in another class iOS

Tags: ios, xcode4, uibutton, core-location

I have seen al most all the other posts about this, but I can't seem to get it. I am new to iOS and objective-C, and I am following the Big Nerd Ranch Guides for both Objective-C and iOS. One of the challenges I found on their site is to make a simple CoreLocation app, and I am trying to separate out the code into classes so I can reuse it later if I would like to.

I want to get the button in my ViewController.m file to call locationManager in MyLocation.m file, which is the MyLocation class. I have looked into NSNotificaiton, but I could not get that to work correctly either.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am missing or doing wrong. I apologize for the simplicity of the question, and I am trying to learn as many basics as possible.

Below are my files:

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyLocation.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)GetLocation:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *LocationOutput;

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyLocation.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize LocationOutput;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setLocationOutput:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)GetLocation:(id)sender {

    //WHAT GOES HERE?
}
@end
```

MyLocation.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@class MyLocation;

@protocol MyLocationDelegate <NSObject>;

@end

@interface MyLocation : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end
```

MyLocation.m:

```
#import "MyLocation.h"

@implementation MyLocation
@synthesize locationManager = _locationManager;

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"Latitude is: %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude);
}

@end
```

I know I am not outputting anything yet to the label, but I am doing an NSLog.

Thank you for any help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to send messages to an object, you need to have a reference to it. In the two classes you are posting, you have the same issue: you don't have a reference to them, so you won't be able to send them messages.

In `ViewController`, you need to somehow get a reference to a `MyLocation` object. For example, if you changed your code to:

```
- (IBAction)GetLocation:(id)sender {
    MyLocation *myLocation = [[[MyLocation alloc] init] autorelease];
    [myLocation someMethod];
}
```

This will, on each call to the action, instantiate a new `MyLocation` object, and send it the `someMethod` message. In your case, this is a little bit more complex. Your `MyLocation` class needs to have an instance of `CLLocationManager` instantiated. Probably, you need an instance variable for it and do something like this:

```
@interface MyLocation {
    CLLocationManager *_locationMananger;
}
@end

@implementation MyLocation

- (id)init {
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
       _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
       _locationManager.delegate = self;
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
   [_locationManager release];

   [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Then, the `CLLocationManager` instance you created on `MyLocation` will call its delegate method when the location changes. What you should do in that method, is store that location in some instance variable of `MyLocation`, so you can access it at a later point.

Finally, I would change the `ViewController` to create the `MyLocation` instance only once, at its initialization, or view load:

```
@interface ViewController {
    MyLocation *_myLocation;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)bundle {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:bundle];
    if (self) {
        _myLocation = [[MyLocation alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
   [_myLocation release];
   [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction)GetLocation:(id)sender {
   // Grab the location from _myLocation using a property or method defined
}

@end
```

Hope you get the idea and this can get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much. This does make it much more clear. However my program stops when the botton hits the `[myLocation locationManager]`line. It goes to the `@synthesize locationManager = _locationManager;` in MyLocation.m and then does nothing. What am I missing on that? I thought I was feeling more comfortable, until today. Thank you again.

Comment: Please recheck the sample, code I just made a correction: when you assign the objects to your instance variables, don't autorelease them!

Comment: Thanks for the update and all of your help. I did not have the autorelease because I am using the built in auto reference control and it is still stuck stuck at that same line. It seems like it cannot find locationManager method

Comment: Thanks again. I was able to work out the last bit there and your code helped a great deal.